How can I generate multiple entities in a from a single request using Amplify?
Amplify allows the creation of entities through generated code. I'd like to harness this to create several entities at once.
When a user creates an entity, say Event,
const Event = a
  .model({
    id: a.id().required(),
    title: a.string(),
    eventOwnerId: a.id().required(),
    eventOwner: a.belongsTo("EventOwner", "eventOwnerId"),
    ...
  })
  .authorization((allow) => [allow.owner()]);

where
const EventOwner = a
  .model({
    id: a.id().required(),
    userId: a.id().required(), // should be associated with a user
    eventId: a.id().required(),
    events: a.hasMany("Event", "eventOwnerId"),
  })
  .authorization((allow) => [allow.owner()]);,

a given property on that event, say eventOwner should be automatically populated through the following process.

If an EventOwner is associated with the user who submitted the createEvent mutation, the created event will automatically be associated via that EventOwner via its eventOwnerId.
If an EventOwner is not associated with the user who submitted the createEvent mutation, the created event will automatically generate a EventOwner entity. And, that EventOwner should automatically be associated with the newly created Event.

I believe this should be accomplished through a lambda function. So, I believe should have

an amplify/functions/pre-event-creation/resource.ts with `import { defineFunction } from "@aws-amplify/backend";

export const preEventCreation = defineFunction({name: "pre-event-creation",});`


and an amplify/functions/pre-event-creation/handler.ts, which I suspect should look something like:

import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import { generateClient } from "aws-amplify/data";
import type { PostConfirmationTriggerHandler } from "aws-lambda";
import { type Schema } from "../../data/schema";
import { preEventCreation } from "./resource";
import { env } from "$amplify/env/post-confirmation";

Amplify.configure(
  {
    API: {
      GraphQL: {
        endpoint: env.AMPLIFY_DATA_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
        region: env.AWS_REGION,
        defaultAuthMode: "iam",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    Auth: {
      credentialsProvider: {
        getCredentialsAndIdentityId: async () => ({
          credentials: {
            accessKeyId: env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            sessionToken: env.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
          },
        }),
        clearCredentialsAndIdentityId: () => {
          /* noop */
        },
      },
    },
  }
);

const client = generateClient<Schema>({
  authMode: "iam",
});

export const handler: PostConfirmationTriggerHandler = async (event) => {
  await client.graphql({
    query: preEventCreation,
    variables: {
      input: {
        email: event.request.userAttributes.email,
        profileOwner: `${event.request.userAttributes.sub}::${event.userName}`,
      },
    },
  });

  return event;
};

Specifically, I'd like to know what to add to the handler. Thanks in advance!
I've tried variations on the PostConfirmationTriggerHandler from the amplify docs, but haven't made much headway.
